# Problemas ao instalar modulo numpy no windows pelo pip

Tags: python, pip, numpy

Consigo instalar outro módulos utilizando o `pip`, exceto o `numpy`. Já tentei outras formas de instalação usando o `easy_install` e instalação pelo `src`, sem êxito também.

Vejam a saída da tentativa de instalação pelo `pip`:
[image: Saída da instalação pelo pip]

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou baixá-lo [precompilado](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)?

Comment: N. Como seria isso?

Comment: Simple. Você vai no link, baixa a biblioteca já pronta, em um arquivo wheel (.whl) e usa PIP para instalar, tipo: `pip install numpy‑1.10.1+mkl‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl`